# Do I need runtime permissions to open a local html file created by the app in android

Tags: android, file, permissions

I am trying to open a previously created html by the app with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(htmlFile), "text/html");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
```

and the emulator with api 23 says error denied. Shall I request again for permissions?

Comment: "error denied" what is denied? access to a local file?

Comment: It's better to show the full stack trace.

Comment: You are not accessing a file on Android with the code in your question. You are asking a third-party app to open a file. Whether it can or not depends entirely upon what the value of `htmlFile` is.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot open the file because I need to go settings/ apps and set Browser Permissions open from storage..

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use webView.,to load the html page directly inside the app.

```
web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
web.loadData(html, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```

In the above line html can either be a string containing the required html.If the html is is some file then you can first load the file and read it into a string.

```
String html="<html>\n" +
            "<body>\n" +
            "<\body>\n" +
            "<\html>\n";
```

This way is not so efficient, but can be useful in some cases